# MongoDB 3.2.11 { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: top", "code" : 59 }

Tags: mongodb

We run a sharded Cluster

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
mongos> db.adminCommand("top")
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: top", "code" : 59 }
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.runCommand( { top: 1 } )
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: top", "code" : 59 }
```

According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/top/) for our version this command should exist.

> top is an administrative command that returns usage statistics for
>   each collection. top provides amount of time, in microseconds, used
>   and a count of operations for the following event types.

The user executing this command have `ClusterMonitor` rights. I tried with a root/admin user and receive the same error.

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.runCommand({buildInfo:1})
{
        "version" : "3.2.11",
        "gitVersion" : "009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4",
        "modules" : [
                "enterprise"
        ],
        "allocator" : "tcmalloc",
        "javascriptEngine" : "mozjs",
        "sysInfo" : "deprecated",
        "versionArray" : [
                3,
                2,
                11,
                0
        ],
        "openssl" : {
                "running" : "OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014",
                "compiled" : "OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014"
        },
        "buildEnvironment" : {
                "distmod" : "ubuntu1404",
                "distarch" : "x86_64",
                "cc" : "/opt/mongodbtoolchain/bin/gcc: gcc (GCC) 4.8.2",
                "ccflags" : "-fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -Werror -O2 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-missing-braces -fno-builtin-memcmp",
                "cxx" : "/opt/mongodbtoolchain/bin/g++: g++ (GCC) 4.8.2",
                "cxxflags" : "-Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -std=c++11",
                "linkflags" : "-fPIC -pthread -Wl,-z,now -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--warn-execstack -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-E",
                "target_arch" : "x86_64",
                "target_os" : "linux"
        },
        "bits" : 64,
        "debug" : false,
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "storageEngines" : [ ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `db.runCommand({buildInfo:1})`

Comment: @PeteGarafano added the requested output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for missing this before, but you are connected to a `mongos`. The `mongos` does not have a `top` command, see [SERVER-11481](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11481) and the associated [DOCS-9014](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-9014) ticket to update the documentation. I suggest taking a look at the [Monitoring for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/monitoring/) documentation for alternatives.